# How does backtracking work in this "Generate Parentheses" question?

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, parentheses

I put the code below in a debugger and saw that for a base case of n=2 when the function reaches line 7, the return statement, it goes back and pops the last 3 parentheses. Why is this, I thought that the return statement is supposed to exit the function?

```
stack = []
res = []
n=2
def backtrack(openN, closedN):
  if openN == closedN ==n:
     res.append("".join(stack))
     return

  if openN < n:
     stack.append("(")
     backtrack(openN+1, closedN)
     stack.pop()

  if closedN < openN:
     stack.append(")")
     backtrack(openN, closedN+1)
     stack.pop()

backtrack(0,0)
print(res)
```

The result is : `['(())', '()()']`

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: Show us *exactly* what you don't understand from when you traced the intermediate expressions in this code. "Explain this code block to me" is out of scope for Stack Overflow: deconstruct the compound expressions and tell us what you don't understand about one or two of those operations.  Your posted code defines a class that you never instantiate -- the code simply exits after the definition.  There is no output showing multiple parentheses, popping, or any such execution.

Comment: The function is recursive. It exits the current invocation, but not the caller.

Comment: @Barmar could you expand on that. I do not know what you mean by invocation and caller.

Comment: Do you understand the general concept of recursion? When `backtrack()` calls itself recursively, and it returns, it's back in the original call.

Comment: Each time it calls itself, the previous state is saved on a stack, and return pops from the stack reverting to the previous state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is instructive to add debug print statements to trace through the operation.

We call generateParenthesis.  That calls backtrack, with the default parameter S = [].  We get to the second `if`, append a ( and call backtrack again.  That takes the same path, and calls backtrack again.  Now the call stack is:

```
generateParenthesis
  backtrack([], 0, 0)
    backtrac(['('], 1, 0)
      backtrack(['(','('], 2, 0)
```

This time, `left` is not less than `n`, so we take the third `if`.  We append a right paren and call backtrack again.  That takes the same path, so we end up with:

```
generateParenthesis
  backtrack([], 0, 0)
    backtrack(['('], 1, 0)
      backtrack(['(','('], 2, 0)
        backtrack(['(','(',')'], 2, 1)
          backtrack(['(','(',')',')'], 2, 2)
```

At this point, `len(S) == 2 * n` is true, so we take the first option.  We append to the `ans` list and return, but that only returns from that innermost call.

```
generateParenthesis
  backtrack([], 0, 0)
    backtrack(['('], 1, 0)
      backtrack(['(','('], 2, 0)
        backtrack(['(','(',')'], 2, 1)
```

That call was left in the middle of the third `if`.  It pops from S and returns, leaving us with

```
generateParenthesis
  backtrack([], 0, 0)
    backtrack(['('], 1, 0)
      backtrack(['(','('], 2, 0)
```

and so on, until the final call returns.